# Bootstrap 4 Menu centered when shown on mobile

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I would like to create a menu that looks like this:
[image]
I managed with this code but when I go and check the responsiveness on a mobile phone, I end up with something like this:

[image]

```
<div  id = "menu" style = "display: flex; justify-content: center;">
            <div class="row">    
                <div class="input-group">
                <span style="color:black" class="input-group-addon">
                     <select id="selection" onchange="getValues(this.value)">
                     <option>Choose Category</option>
                     <option>Notary</option>
                     <option>Deed Date</option>
                     <option>Person</option>
                     <option>Place</option>
                     <option>Manuscript Reference</option>
                     <option>Subject</option>
                     </select>
                    </span>
                    <input class="autocomplete"id="search" type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Choose a category" style ="max-width:200px;" disabled=true >
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="searchButton" onclick="doSparql(this.value)"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I would like to show the menu centered. Is it somehow possible? Furthermore why Choose Category drop down menu and the text box do not have the same height?

[image]

Comment: Why are the 2 class attributes on the input? Are the other CSS styles you haven't show?

Comment: form-control class can be removed. There is only this CSS that is not shown: .input-group-addon {



  padding: 0!important;



}

Comment: why is form-control removed? ... that's the standard bootstrap form control, are you using a select plugin?

Answer (score 1):

rows (`.row`) are only meant to directly contain columns (`.col-*`) (not `.input-group`)

style both inputs the same, and the centering should work fine..

```
<div id="menu" class="py-4 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span style="color:black" class="input-group-addon">
                <select id="selection" class="form-control" onchange="getValues(this.value)">
                    <option>Choose Category</option>
                    <option>Notary</option>
                    <option>Deed Date</option>
                    <option>Person</option>
                    <option>Place</option>
                    <option>Manuscript Reference</option>
                    <option>Subject</option>
                </select>
            </span>
            <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Choose a category" style="max-width:200px;" disabled=true>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="searchButton" onclick="doSparql(this.value)"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/J6xnSneTr4